# Aviary Photo Editor Presenting Challenge

Tags: editor, photo, aviary

I am stuck here. I want to implement Aviary Photo Editor into my app.

The Aviary itself is a UINavigationController as the manual says, so it is not possible to present it from already existing navigation controller which is what my app stands on.

What would be the alternatives for this situation?

The console displays this message:

**Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

Please help someone (:

Thanks.

Comment: I pushed on my app and it worked. Have you tried it?